# R - stat_contour() - Not possible to generate contour data

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I have approx. 4800 lat/lon points with a noise level, that I would like to draw contours on (e.g. 50dB, 55dB, ...). You can have a look at the data here: https://pastebin.com/LkfWYwJe

When I run

```
ggplot(
  data,
  aes(x =Lat, Lon, z = Value)
) + stat_contour(binwidth = 10)
```

I receive a

```
Warning message:
Not possible to generate contour data
```

Unfortunately I don't have any idea why this happens. Derived from other questions here, I tried less data, but this did not have an effect.

Any hint/advice/remark is higly appreciated. Thanks!

---

*Edit:* The problem seems to be unrelated to data not building a grid. I uploaded new sample data, which forms a perfect grid. https://pastebin.com/F4c7hWcY This dataset shows the very same issue as described above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - ggplot - stat\_contour not able to generate contour lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065290/r-ggplot-stat-contour-not-able-to-generate-contour-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data file doesn't seem to have pairs of values for each possible combination of Lat and Long - instead, every `Lat` value is only present one time in the data.frame. The same holds true for the `Lon` varibale:

```
data[data$Lat == data$Lat[1],]
```

results in

```
#    X      Lat      Lon DayNoise
# 1 98 12.69871 52.49891 31.70291
```

When you round the data it *kind of* works:

```
data$Lat <- round(data$Lat,digits = 3)
data$Lon <- round(data$Lon,digits = 3)
ggplot(data,   aes(x=Lat, y=Lon, z=Value)) + 
  stat_contour(binwidth=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My example dataset above is derived from a perfectly evenly spaced grid. Unfortunately I'm not able to compute the whole set as this kills my RAM.

But I created a small part from my original dataset, which shows the very same problem with ggplot while being perfectly evenly spaced. https://pastebin.com/F4c7hWcY

Nevertheless, thanks herbaman!

Comment: Hm, you're right, I misinterpreted something. See my updated anwser.

Comment: It seems, that my "grid" is somewhat convex. I guess this is related to the map projection used in my simulation software. Taking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065290/r-ggplot-stat-contour-not-able-to-generate-contour-lines into account I was able to draw a contour. Thanks for your advice, that pointed me into the right direction!