# Add contour on ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Firstly, this is my dataset.

```
Lon     Lat CPUE    Temperature
120.93  27  0.00    24.3
121.18  27  0.62    24.2
121.43  27  3.76    24.9
121.6   27.25   0.87    25
121.35  27.25   1.63    24.2
121.1   27.25   2.66    24.8
121.25  27.5    7.37    24.9
121.5   27.5    6.26    25.2
121.75  27.5    12.02   19.4
121.95  27.75   30.40   18.5
121.7   27.75   93.81   23.1
121.65  28  282.83  27.1
121.9   28  10.43   22.3
122.15  28  36.11   18.2
122.4   28.25   170.05  17.9
122.15  28.25   1170.97 18.8
122.3   28.5    0.00    18.4
122.55  28.5    149.99  17.6
122.8   28.75   118.27  18.5
122.55  28.75   1838.31 17.6
122.25  29  1218.93 21.2
122.5   29  1245.63 18.7
122.75  29  235.07  17.9 123    29  33.01   19.1
```

And this is my ggmap with CPUE data point:

[image: ggmap]

I wonder if I can add temperature contour on this ggmap.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach, taking reference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078830/8449629) as there's insufficient data points in the dataframe to generate contour data:

```
# generate regular grid since geom_contour doesn't work on this dataset
temp <- akima::interp(df$Lon, df$Lat, df$Temperature)
df.expanded <- expand.grid(x = temp$x, y = temp$y)
df.expanded$z <- as.vector(temp$z)
df.expanded <- na.omit(df.expanded)
rm(temp)

library(ggplot2)

# plot contour using stat_contour() on expanded data frame
ggmap(background) +
  stat_contour(data = df.expanded, binwidth = 1,
               aes(x=x,y=y,z=z)) +
  geom_point(data = df, alpha = 0.5,
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, size = CPUE))
```

[image: ggmap plot]

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Lon     Lat CPUE    Temperature
120.93  27  0.00    24.3
                 121.18  27  0.62    24.2
                 121.43  27  3.76    24.9
                 121.6   27.25   0.87    25
                 121.35  27.25   1.63    24.2
                 121.1   27.25   2.66    24.8
                 121.25  27.5    7.37    24.9
                 121.5   27.5    6.26    25.2
                 121.75  27.5    12.02   19.4
                 121.95  27.75   30.40   18.5
                 121.7   27.75   93.81   23.1
                 121.65  28  282.83  27.1
                 121.9   28  10.43   22.3
                 122.15  28  36.11   18.2
                 122.4   28.25   170.05  17.9
                 122.15  28.25   1170.97 18.8
                 122.3   28.5    0.00    18.4
                 122.55  28.5    149.99  17.6
                 122.8   28.75   118.27  18.5
                 122.55  28.75   1838.31 17.6
                 122.25  29  1218.93 21.2
                 122.5   29  1245.63 18.7
                 122.75  29  235.07  17.9 123    29  33.01   19.1")
```

Background map data:

```
library(ggmap)
background <- get_map(location = c(min(df$Lon),
                                   min(df$Lat),
                                   max(df$Lon),
                                   max(df$Lat)),
                      zoom = 8)
```